# Removing additional .tar.gz in the extension from several files in bash

Tags: linux, bash, rename, file-extension

I had a bash script responsible for moving and compressing some old log files under a directory every day.

Making some tests i noticed the script was compressing recursively every compressed file again and again, so now i have a bunch of files with the filename like: $files.log(.tar.gz * N days).

Could be possible to remove every extra .tar.gz from all these files?

Comment: You cannot simply remove the multiplied file name extension, you have to decompress every step again, otherwise you will not be able to use the files later. A file compressed a second time differs from the state after the first compression.

Comment: For the action you want to take a look at the `find` utility and its `exec` feature.

Comment: You might want to have a look at "logrotate", which you can easily set up to automatically compress and rename your old log files in a nice configurable way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a simple inline command like this:

```
for old in *.tar.gz; do mv $old ${old%%.tar*}.tar.gz; done
```

This will find every file finished by .tar.gz

${old%%.tar*} will get all the filename and extensions until the first '.tar' found.

Then we just add .tar.gz again, and we have the work done.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

> Even if you will remove the extra .tar.gz extension from the file, it
>   won't be useful check the below example -

```
Compress : 
ls -ltr file1
tar -cvzf file1.tar.gz file1
tar -cvzf file1.tar.gz.tar.gz file1.tar.gz
```

> Rename :

```
mv -f file1.tar.gz.tar.gz file1.tar.gz
```

> Uncompress :

```
tar -xvf file1.tar.gz.tar.gz
generated file : file1.tar.gz
```

> means file1.tar.gz(which is in actual .tar.gz.tar.gz) generated
>   file1.tar.gz so you have to again uncompress the file.
>
> In order to avoid this - you need to make changes in your script. 
>   while selecting the file for compression you should avoid the already
>   compressed files using below cmd

```
find . -type f -name "file*" ! -name "*tar.gz"
```

Comment: you need to use tar -xvzf to untar a gzip, you missed the 'z' out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to untar every file but keep one level of compression, i.e. you uncompress them all the way to their *.tar.gz form, you can do something like that:

```
while ls *.tar.gz.tar.gz &> /dev/null; do find -name '*.tar.gz.tar.gz' | while read f; do tar xfz "$f" && rm -f "$f"; done; done
```

The first `while` statement is there to loop while there is at least one file ending with .tar.gz.tar.gz:

```
while ls *.tar.gz.tar.gz &> /dev/null; do
```

The second `while` statement piped from `find` is there to parse all the current .tar.gz.tar.gz

```
find -name '*.tar.gz.tar.gz' | while read f
```

Please note that if one extraction fails, the loop will run infinitely because you will always have a .tar.gz.tar.gz file, so the first loop will never end.